# I'm unable to create the .exe for the most simple 'hello world' example

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe

I've used py2exe successfully for previous projects on previous build machines, but now I've freshly installed everything from scratch and can't run the simplest example:

**setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
  
setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

**hello.py**:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Command: `python3 setup.py py2exe`
Output:

```
running py2exe

  1 missing Modules
  ------------------
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
Building 'dist\hello.exe'.
error: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect.
```

**dest\hello.exe** is generated (37 kB!) but gives the following error when run:

```
Could not locate script resource:The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.
FATAL ERROR: Could not locate script
```

The versions I have installed are:

```
python --version
Python 3.8.6

pip freeze
cachetools==4.1.1
future==0.18.2
numpy==1.19.3
opencv-python==4.4.0.46
pefile==2019.4.18
py2exe==0.10.1.0
pyreadline==2.1
pywin32==300

systeminfo
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Hotfix(s):                 6 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4580419
                           [02]: KB4561600
                           [03]: KB4577266
                           [04]: KB4580325
                           [05]: KB4586864
                           [06]: KB4586781
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

I know that there is clearly something weird happening (I've already hit the issue with 'numpy' here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html ) ... but I can't quite see what it is.

Thanks !

-- Mac

Answer (score 0):

You just misstyped the command line flag, should be: `python setup.py py2exe`.
Works fine for me on Win7, Python 3.8.0:

```
(py38) λ python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe

  2 missing Modules
  ------------------
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
Building 'dist\hello.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\users\f3k\envs\py38\scripts\python38.dll to dist
...
Copy DLL C:\Python38\DLLs\libffi-7.dll to dist\

C:\temp
(py38) λ dist\hello.exe
Hello World
```

Comment: Apologies - that was a typo when copying the message.  I did type it correctly on the command line.  I've edited the post to correct my typo.